# Ionic get integer ID from JSON data

Tags: javascript, json, ionic-framework

This should be a very simple thing to do. I am building an IONIC app with a JSON data file. The data is something like this.

```
[
  { "id": 1,
    "name": "John",
    "type": "male",
    "bio": "this is John"
  },
  { "id": 10,
    "name": "Mary",
    "type": "female",
    "bio": "this is Mary"
  }
]
```

Now I want to filter by by "type" in the data and then loop the data by "id".

```
<ion-list ng-repeat="person in people | filter:   {'type': 'male'}">
  <ion-item href="#tab/people/males/{{ person.id }}">{{ person.name }}
</ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

The Controller for this is:

```
.controller('PeopleController', ['$scope', '$state', '$http', function($scope, $state, $http){
$http.get('data/people.json').success(function(data){
$scope.people = data;
$scope.whichPerson = $state.params.id;
}),
}])
```

This displays the required data of males only by name.

However if I want to see the individual bio using the following code

```
<div class="card" ng-repeat="person in people | filter: { id: whichPerson }">
<h2>{{ person.name }}</h2>
<p>{{ person.bio}}</p>
</div>
```

When I click the individual item for each person to display person.bio I get both John and Mary.'

I figured this was because the "id" is 1 and 10 which seems to be parsing as a string to the controller. I tried putting this

```
"id": "1" and "id": "10"
```

Did not work. I did this in the controller

```
$scope.whichPerson = parseInt($state.params.id, 10);
```

This does not work either. I am totally stumped. How do I get the individual id's from the data? In fact I noticed that I can change the id to 11 or 12 or 13 etc and it still returns both records?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Can you confirm that `$scope.whichPerson` is being assigned correctly?

Comment: Yes, everything is working correctly. If I change filter to "name" everything works fine but not with the id and I can't figure out why

Comment: @kolli is right, you need to add a comparator `filter: { id: whichPerson }:true`, just make sure `$scope.whichPerson` is an integer to match your json data

Comment: Nope! That doesn't do it. This will not return anything. The value of 'id' is an integer (double or is that triple checked now). If I try strict returns all entries. At the moment I've changed code to go with 'name' not 'id' but of course this is not efficient in case of duplicate in name. Oh, I did check the value passed is correct through the console.log even assigned to another var.

Answer (score 2):

Try to add the comparator `:true` to your filter as described in the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter). This forces a strict comparison of the filter value instead of just checking if the data contains it.

Comment: No, neither 'true' or 'strict' works, True doesn't return anything and strict returns all records...

Comment: @boony strict is not a keyword, that's just a variable used in the example. Can you set up a CodePen or Plunker or something that reproduces this? When I try it, it works fine with :true ...

Comment: Damn! Hold yer horses. After much head banging I did some further error checking and I determined that the 'id' was not returning an integer after all. I returned to  trying the parseInt and this time it worked. Not sure why it was not working yesterday but seems like problem is now solved.

Answer (score 0):

Given the above doesn't work, you could try a custom filter by doing:

```
filter: { id: whichPerson }:sameID
```

and then in your controller:

```
$scope.sameID = function(actual, expected) {
        return parseInt(actual) === parseInt(expected)
    };
```

Even if this doesn't work, you could then at least debug within the custom filter to see where the comparison is failing